# Laravel localhost API Error 404 While /public is working

Tags: laravel, api, localhost

Hi This is my 2nd Post here.... I been searching over the internet for almost 12 hours and so far nothing can help me so i decide to post here. I just finish my CMS and i would like to start my API and ......

My Problem is my API route is not working properly : 
[My Postman ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iggAv.jpg)

But When I am running my other file in CMS is working :
[My Brower Localhost CMS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlDs1.jpg)

My Route :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1' ,'namespace' => 'V1', 'middleware' => 'JsonApiMiddleware'], function(){


    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
```

My Folder and File Location :
[My API Location and Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVLlx.jpg)

Comment: Do `/laravel/public/api/v1/login` or `/laravel/public/api/v1/login` work?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are specifically doing in each screenshot? It looks like your first one is sending a post request, and the second one is a get request to show the login page. Also, you seem to be trying to post to `/laravel/v1/api/login`, but your post route, as described, is set up as `/login`. Was that intentional?

Comment: i donno why my API link doesn't work... then 2nd picture is to prove my link to my CMS is working but my API is not working.... My 1st doing API..

Answer (score 1):

Hi I manage to solve it after talking to many people and learn about the PHP ARTISAN SERVE....

The Actual Path for the postman to work is : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login
and you need to type "php artisan serve" in your command line in your laravel folder to start web server for laravel. Then my API is working perfectly. Coz the CMS is already handle by the Xampp but the API cannot run on Xampp based on my PC configuration.